# C# Output Log Padding

Tags: c#, text, padding

I'm writing a log parser and want to sort the output data into columns, and at the moment use this code:

```
string OEMVersion = string.Format("{0,-20} {1}", "OEM Version", GetXMLData(doc, "OemMarkerVersion"));
string OEMID = string.Format("{0,-20} {1}", "OEM ID", GetXMLData(doc, "OemId"));
string OEMTableID = string.Format("{0,-20} {1}", "OEM TableID", GetXMLData(doc, "OemTableId"));
string Manufacturer = string.Format("{0,-20} {1}", "Manufacturer", GetXMLData(doc, "Manufacturer"));
string Model = string.Format("{0,-20} {1}", "Model", GetXMLData(doc, "Model"));
```

To sort the padding out but the output only looks okay with certain fonts (Consolas, Lucinda Console etc.). How can I pad the columns with tabs rather than spaces to overcome this? string.Format() doesn't seem to allow me to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Fonts with proportional width don't align so easily. Also if you use tabs.

Comment: Even with Tabs, depending on your content, your output may not align correctly. Meaning if your 2nd "Manufacturer" value has 4 or 8 more characters than the 1st, then the tab will push the 2nd one out.

Comment: I wish to know the reason for this alignment. If these variables are simply written to a file then there is no need to worry. The current code aligns them perfectly, it is just a matter of using the correct font. If these variables should be outputted on video then I suggest to use a `ListView` or a `DataGridView` to have the data aligned by columns and rows with no effort to manually align them

Comment: Thank you all for your replies, I guess a solution just doesn't exist for what I want. @Steve, it's simply written to a new text file and I wanted a nice neat output for all fonts but by the sound of things it just can't be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a tab character to your formats?

```
string OEMVersion = string.Format("{0,-20}\t{1}", "OEM Version", GetXMLData(doc, "OemMarkerVersion"));
string OEMID = string.Format("{0,-20}\t{1}", "OEM ID", GetXMLData(doc, "OemId"));
string OEMTableID = string.Format("{0,-20}\t{1}", "OEM TableID", GetXMLData(doc, "OemTableId"));
string Manufacturer = string.Format("{0,-20}\t{1}", "Manufacturer", GetXMLData(doc, "Manufacturer"));
string Model = string.Format("{0,-20}\t{1}", "Model", GetXMLData(doc, "Model"));
```

You may want to keep the space padding to reduce the risk of tabs after shorter strings not going past the tabs of longer strings.  Won;t be 100% accurate with proportional fonts but should be cleaner.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a play with this and see what the results are like.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align properly your variables on a video output when a variable width font is used, then you need the help of some kind of tabular control like a `ListView` or a `DataGridView`
(I am assuming a WinForm app but the concepts are the same for other technologies).

The use of a control is preferable because the alternative is to measure the length in pixels of every string and use [Graphics.DrawString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring(v=vs.110).aspx) to position your string parts at the exact pixel position.

Let me show an example using a ListView

```
// Create a new ListView control. (or use the designer)
ListView listView1 = new ListView();
// Position and size of the ListView
listView1.Bounds = new Rectangle(new Point(10,10), new Size(500,200));
// Some display feature....
listView1.View = View.Details;
listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
listView1.GridLines = false;

// Add OEM Version value
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("OEM Version");
item.SubItems.Add(GetXMLData(doc, "OemMarkerVersion"));
listView1.Items.Add(item);

// Add OEM ID value
item = new ListViewItem("OEM ID");
item.SubItems.Add( GetXMLData(doc, "OemId"));
listView1.Items.Add(item);

... and so on for the others values and labels ....

// Some header formatting
listView1.Columns.Add("Label", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Data", 400, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

// Put the ListView on video....
yourForm.Controls.Add(listView1);
```

Comment: The output has to be a text file so using a control won't work (it's a console app as well - my apologies for missing out this detail), but thank you for the code, it's very interesting!